# Showing Runtime ErrorAbort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Tags: c++, arrays, signals, sigabrt, abort

```html
// Sum of Sub-Array

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

  
void firstSubArray(vector<int> arr, int size, int sum)
{
    int newSum = 0;
    int beginPos=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        newSum += arr.at(i);
        if(newSum > sum)
        {
            newSum = newSum - arr.front();
            arr.erase(arr.begin());
            beginPos++;
        }
        if(newSum == sum) {
            cout << beginPos + 1 << " " << i + 1;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout<<"-1";
}


int main()
{
    int testCases;
    cin>>testCases;
    int size, sum;
    int temp;

    for(int j = 0; j<testCases; j++) {
        cin>>size>>sum;
        vector<int>arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cin >> temp;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        }
        firstSubArray(arr, size, sum);
        cout<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Question:** Given an unsorted array A of size N of non-negative integers, find a continuous sub-array which adds to a given number S. My code gives correct ans for the given test cases but shows a run time error on submitting.

**Error:**
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorAbort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

**Link:** [Question Link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/subarray-with-given-sum/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a position in the vector that does not exist.  The executor on the server detects this condition and aborts.  As a first step, change the `arr` to `vector < int > const &arr`.

Comment: but i don't want to make the array/vector constant because I need to erase the front element in the program. Also kindly clarify how does it try to access out of range position.

Comment: The task at hand does not mention erasing the front element and I can see no reason to do so.  When you modify the underlying container, you invalidate any indexes you may have into it.